# what does "drive one's hands together" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Here's the sentence:
Inside her muff, Anna drove her hands together.

I can't find the meaning of the expression anywhere. 
I thought "clasped her hands" but not sure.

Comment: It's not a fixed phrase or idiom: it means exactly what it says, with *drive* in its core sense, from which all other senses are derived, = "push, impel".

Comment: Anna is pushing her hands hard against each other. As @StoneyB says, you can get this from the dictionary meaning.

Answer (score 1):

As StoneyB said, it literally means that she is pushing them towards each other. The word was probably chosen because it implies force or tension -- most likely reflecting her emotions or something else in the story.